# If I've migrated from iPhoto to Photos, can I safely delete the migrated photo library?

Tags: photos, photos.app, migration

I used to have iPhoto on my machine and have migrated to Photos. I notice now that I have two photo libraries on my machine that are taking up over 10 GB each. I'd like to reclaim disk space, but I don't know if I can safely delete one of them.

The two files are:

- Photos Library.photoslibrary (15.6 GB)
- iPhoto Library.migratedPhotoLibrary (11.3 GB)

I'm inclined to think that I can delete the second one because it has "iPhoto" in the name, but I'm unsure of if it is still being used by the new app. Can I safely delete the migrated photo library?

Comment: [This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/282371/128872) to a related question covers your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have been using Photos only since migration you can safely delete it. The purpose of the migratedPhotoLibrary is so you still can use iPhoto with your old pictures (and perhaps import new ones to iPhoto only, **if you have done this**, then no, don't delete it.) After deleting it you can delete your iPhoto app as well.

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204655

Comment: However, this won't necessarily save much space. Photos that were already in iPhoto are not copied to Photos, [only a reference to the same source file is made](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204476). You would only save space if you deleted photos in Photos that are still in iPhoto. But it is still safe to delete the iPhotos library: as long as a photo in the Photos library, it will still be on disk (technically this is done via hard links to the same file).

Comment: Open terminal, `CD ~/Pictures/` then `sudo rm -r -f "iPhoto Library.migratedphotolibrary"/`

Comment: Hmm, seems like all it did was merge the two folders after I tried to delete "iPhoto Library.migratedphotolibrary"